# Obtendo id de registro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma tabela com vários registros e um link para exclusão, como eu faço para ao clicar nesse link passar o valor do id do registro em que eu quero deletar ? 
Código da minha view:

```
@model IList<Financas.Entidades.Usuario>

@Html.ActionLink("Novo Usuário", "Form")
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var usuario in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@usuario.Id</td>
                    <td>@usuario.Nome</td>
                    <td>@usuario.Email</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Excluir","Excluir","Usuario")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Excluir(int? usuario)
    {
            try
            {
                IList<Usuario> dados = usuarioDAO.GetById(usuario);
                return View(dados);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos tratar primeiro dos erros em seu código.

O erro da pergunta é simples, você não está passando nada como parâmetro à **Action**. Basta alterar para o seguinte:

```
   <td>@Html.ActionLink("Excluir","Excluir","Usuario", new{usuario = usuario.Id})</td>
```

Dessa forma você estará passando um **ID** para o parâmetro `usuario` em sua **Action**.

Agora vamos fazer algumas melhorias em seu código?

A **primeira**:

Não sei o que está em seu `usuarioDAO`, mas aparentemente você está apenas listando uma lista de usuários por **ID**. Em nenhum momento em seu código existe uma opção de excluir.

```
public ActionResult Excluir(int? usuario)
        {
                try
                {
                    IList<Usuario> dados = usuarioDAO.GetById(usuario);
                    return View(dados);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
```

**Segunda:**

Se você não possui uma **View** de confirmação de exclusão, porque deixar a opção de passar um **ID** `null`? Se você vai excluir um usuário, tem que ser passado algum dado, ou seja, você pode alterar o parâmetro de `int? usuario` para `int usuario`. Dessa forma estará garantindo que sempre terá um valor.

**Terceira**:

Eu mudaria sua lógica toda apenas por isso:

```
public ActionResult Excluir(int id)
            Usuario usuario= db.Usuarios.Find(id);

            if(usuario == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);//Um erro aqui, pois o usuário não foi encontrado

            db.Usuarios.Remove(usuario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Indice");
}
```

Comment: Quem faz q exclusao é minha classe DAO, onde implementei: public void excluir(Usuario usuario) { context.Usuario.Remove(usuario); context.saveChanges(); }

Comment: @Desalex Não existe razão para isso. Esse tipo de implementação possui várias respostas aqui no site, basta procurar para entender melhor. Entretanto, o foco da pergunta não é essa. Basta usar apenas a solução postada no início da resposta que irá resolver seu problema, isso é, levando em consideração que sua classe DAO esteja correta.

Comment: entendi, só quis dizer quer quem faz o controle de inserção e deleção da minha aplicação é a camada DAO. Mas obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Answer (score 0):

Só passar assim:

```
Html.ActionLink("Excluir", "Excluir", "Usuario", new {id = usuario.Id}, null)
```

Comment: fiz do jeito que falou, porem ainda vem valor null para o meu controller...

Comment: passa a assinatura da action no controller

Comment: editei e coloquei o codigo do controller no post

Comment: muda para public ActionResult Excluir(int id)

Comment: O parametro passado chama Id. Então você tem que ter um parametro chamado Id na action para o mvc fazer o bind. e eu tirei o nullable do tipo.

Comment: Editei seu controller no post.

Comment: copia a action editada para seu controller

Comment: Mas esse metodo seu não exclui nada. e está dando um getbyid para dentro de uma lista de usuarios em vez de para um usuário.

Comment: preciso listar antes de excluir ? pois no meo DAO está:         public void Excluir(Usuario usuario)
        {
            context.Usuarios.Remove(usuario);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: Se funcionou marca como respondida.